# Ask for MATLAB code to detect steady state of data

Tags: matlab

I have a vector of electrical power consumption data which consists of transient, steady and power off states. I would like to identify steady-state starting point by the following condition:

- The 5 consecutive elements of the data have difference values between each adjacent element <= threshold value (for this case, let say =10 W)
- The first element that meets the condition shows the starting point of steady-state.

Example:

```
data = [0 0 0 40 70 65 59 50 38 30 32 33 30 33 37 19 ...
        0 0 0 41 73 58 43 34 25 39 33 38 34 31 35 38 19 0]

abs(diff(data)) = [0 0 40 30 15 7 9 12 8 3 2 1 3 4 18 19 ...
                   0 0 41 32 15 9 14 6 5 4 3 4 3 19 19 0]
```

The sequences of `abs(diff(data))` that meet the condition are `8 3 2 1 3` and `6 5 4 3 4`. Therefore, the output should show the 10th data element (=30) and 27th data element (=33) as starting point of steady-state (There are 2 times of steady-state detected).

How would I write MATLAB code for this scenario?

(PS: data = 0 shows power off state)

Comment: I presume that you want only the first element even if more than 5 consecutive elements are the same?  Not sure about your conditions for "steady-state" - under that, you could detect a slow rise as "steady state" even if the overall rise was more than 10W.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach using [`nlfilter`](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/images/ref/nlfilter.html) (if the function is not available, you can implement a sliding window yourself):

```
data = [0 0 0 40 70 65 59 50 38 30 32 33 30 33 37 19 0 0 0 41 73 58 43 34 25 39 33 38 34 31 35 38 19 0];
difs = abs(diff(data));
% Use sliding window to find windows of consecutive elements below threshold
steady = nlfilter(difs, [1, 5], @(x)all(x <= 10));
% Find where steady state starts (1) and ends (-1)
start = diff(steady);
% Return indices of starting steady state
ind = find(start == 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for advice. I have used nlfilter command, it can detect the start and stop of steady-state period well. However, since this command detect the specified pattern and locate its position at the center of it (not at the starting point), so data point shifting has to be applied for proper identification.